# How to copy tables from a pdf file to excel file, except the headers using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.7, pypdf

I have extracted Tables from a pdf file to an excel(xlsx) file using python. Now I want All the data except the headers to appear in the excel file. What changes should I make to the code. I am attaching the code below for you.

The code:-

```
import camelot
import PyPDF2
import pandas as pd

# PDF file to extract tables from
file = "C:/Users/mahma_dv2pq9y/Downloads/santander.pdf"

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:/Users/mahma_dv2pq9y/OneDrive/santander_agg_mortgage.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')


# extract all the tables in the PDF file
tables = camelot.read_pdf(file, pages='all',flavor="stream" , encoding="utf-8")
except('Maximum loan to value, Initial rate, Differential to BBR, Product fee, Completion deadline, Minimum loan size, Maximum loan size, Early repayment
charge plus Benefit package, Payable if you repay on or before, product code')
 
#number of tables extracted
print("Total tables extracted:", tables.n)

# print the first table as Pandas DataFrame
#print(tables[1].df)

# export individually as Excel (.xlsx extension)
#tables[1].to_excel("/mnt/projetcs/pdf_excel/agg.xlsx")


columns = ['Additional Info']

for i in range (1, tables.n):
    #print(tables[i].df)
    #tables[i].df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet'+str(i), index=False)
    temp_df = tables[i].df
    #temp_df.rename(columns=temp_df.iloc[0]).drop(temp_df.index[0])
    
    #temp_df.drop(columns, inplace=True, axis=1,errors='ignore')
    # iterating the columns
    for col in temp_df.columns:
        #print(temp_df.iloc[:, [col]])
        if(col>7):
            print(col)
            #print(temp_df.drop(temp_df.iloc[:, [col]], axis=1,errors='ignore'))
            #print(temp_df)
    col_length=len(temp_df. columns);
    print("count"+str(col_length))
    
    if(col_length > 6):
        print("save")
        temp_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet', index=False)

writer.save()
```

Comment: try changing from `temp_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet', index=False)` to
`temp_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet', index=False, header=False)`

Answer (score 0):

I have no Santander Bank Statement to test, but I am almost sure you will manage to adjust it to your needs:

```
import camelot
import pandas as pd

# PDF file to extract tables from
file = r"C:/Users/mahma_dv2pq9y/Downloads/santander.pdf"
    
# extract all the tables in the PDF file
tables = camelot.read_pdf(file, pages='all', flavor="stream", encoding="utf-8")

master_DF = pd.DataFrame() # Creates empty dataframe to update it with data later

for i in range(tables.n):
    if i == 0: # if table is from the firs Statement page to below:
        new_header = tables[i].df.iloc[4] # choose row with headers from tables[0].df  (header's names to list)
        tables[i].df = tables[i].df[5:] # read only data after the header row (top rows usually have lots bank account related info which is not needed)
        tables[i].df.columns = new_header # rename empty headers using list
        master_DF = pd.concat([master_DF, tables[i].df], axis=0, ignore_index=True) # append empty DataFrame with data
    else:
        tables[i].df = tables[i].df[1:] # reading DataFrame without top row (usually bank Statement has Info/Logo row)
        tables[i].df.columns = new_header # rename empty headers using list
        master_DF = pd.concat([master_DF, tables[i].df], axis=0, ignore_index=True) # appending data
        print(tables[i].df)
        print("")

float_cols = ['Debit', 'Credit', 'Balance'] # list of columns with numeric data (float)

for col in float_cols:
    master_DF[col]=master_DF[col].str.replace(",","") # striping out commas before datatype conversion

master_DF[float_cols] = master_DF[float_cols].apply(pd.to_numeric) # datatype conversion: strings converted to numeric

master_DF.to_excel(r"C:/Users/mahma_dv2pq9y/OneDrive/NEW_santander_agg_mortgage.xlsx", index=False, sheet_name="BS_Statement")
print("DATA Saved")
```

Comment: still showing error

Comment: you have not mentioned about errors in the question.
my example, is just example how to append generate one dataframe from each page.

If you would post the location and description of errror, - might help

Comment: Can you make changes to my code instead of a new code?

Comment: Answer, updated... works with NatWest, - for Santander, read comments in the code

Comment: It is showing errors traceback